# Problema al cargar imagen a BD en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problemón con la subida de la imagen a BD MySQL! El proceso se lleva correctamente hasta la subida de la imagen del equipo del usuario a mi servidor, pero después de eso, no se ejecuta la sentencia que se encarga de guardar valores en la BD. Si reviso la carpeta donde se guardan las uploaded images, ahí está la imagen, pero jamás se inserta un registro en la BD...

Este es el código HTML

```
<?php require 'headerAdministratorVistas.php'; ?>

<div class="contenedor"> 

    <div class="slideshow">

    <article>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="posttitle">
        <img src="../images/titleinfoConta.png">
    </div>
    <hr>
    </article>  

    <article>
    <br/>
    <form class="formularioEditar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
        <input type="text" name="concepto" class="contentinfo" placeholder="Forma de Contacto"><br/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="informacion" class="contentinfo" placeholder="Descripción"><br/><br/>
        <input type="file" name="imagen">
        <input type="submit" value="Crear nueva Categoría" class="guardarcambios">
    </form>


    </article>

    </div>
</div>

<?php require 'footer.php'; ?>

Y este, el código PHP

    <?php session_start();

require 'config.php';
require '../functions.php';

comprobarSesion();

$conexion = conexion($bd_config);

if (!$conexion) {
    header('Location: ../error.php');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $concepto = $_POST['concepto'];
    $informacion = $_POST['informacion'];
    $imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];

    $archivo_asubir = '../' . $pagina_config['carpeta_imagenes'] . $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($imagen, $archivo_asubir);

    $statement = $conexion->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO contacto (id, concepto, informacion, image)
    VALUES (null, :concepto, :informacion, :imagen)'
    );

    $statement->execute(array(
    ':concepto' => $concepto,
    ':informacion' => $informacion,
    ':imagen' => $_FILES['imagen']['name']
    ));

   header('Location: '. RUTA . 'admin/mostrarContacto.php');

}

require '../views/nuevoContacto.view.php';  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba controlar si el **INSERT** genero un error usando **[errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.errorinfo.php)**.

Agrega estas lineas debajo del *execute*:

```
$arr = $statement->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);
die();
```

Comment: Marcos, agregué las líneas de código que me dices, y aparece esto: Array ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1048 [2] => Column 'id' cannot be null ). Entonces, si no es null, qué debo escribir???

Comment: Pues, tenes 2 opciones: 1.- Modificar la DB para que `id` sea `autoincrement` **(si es que no lo es y la cual considero la mejor)** y no deberias listar el campo en la consulta (ver respuesta @JoseAPL). 2.- Indicar a `mano` el `id`

Comment: Listo, resuelto!!!! El único, y mínimo error, que me costó mucho, pero que no me vuelve a pasar era que la columna id, no estaba asignada con la prpiedad autoincrement. Al hacer esto, todo funcionó a la perfección!!!!!!!! Muchísmas Gracias!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar tu consulta, no puedes insertar un valor en la base de dato especificando que el `id` sea nulo

Si no quieres especificar manualmente el `id` simplemente ignoralo en tu sentencia.

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare(
' INSERT INTO contacto (concepto, informacion, image)
  VALUES (:concepto, :informacion, :imagen)'
);
```

Comment: Gracias José! Ya intenté, pero no funcionó! borré el id de mi sentencia, y funcionó por un momento, pero en la BD, se insertó un registro con el id 0, y fue lo único, después ya no funcionó.

Comment: Vuelve hacer como te lo he dicho, vacia tu tabla y en el sengudo insert haces un log del `insert` como menciona @marcos-gallardo y ves lo que pasa, asegurate que la columna `id` esta establecido a auto incremental

Comment: Listo, resuelto!!!! El único, y mínimo error, que me costó mucho, pero que no me vuelve a pasar era que la columna id, no estaba asignada con la prpiedad autoincrement. Al hacer esto, todo funcionó a la perfección!!!!!!!! Muchísmas Gracias!! :D